# How to segment the cloth area in the image using python opencv

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, artificial-intelligence

I want to segment cloth in this

[image]

I am using the following code but this only segments the table not the cloth.

```
img = cv2.imread("/content/task5/20210514_153525.jpg",0)
imgplot = plt.imshow(img,cmap='gray')
plt.show()
blur = cv2.blur(img, (3, 3))
ret, thresh = cv2.threshold(blur, 150, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY) 
ker2 = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE,(15,15))
mask = cv2.morphologyEx(np.float32(thresh), cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, ker2)
mask = mask.astype(np.uint8)
contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(image =mask , mode = cv2.RETR_TREE,method = cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
mask1=mask.copy()*0
for i,cnt in enumerate(contours):
    if hierarchy[0][i][2] == -1 :
        if  cv2.contourArea(cnt) > 100000:
            cv2.drawContours(mask1,[cnt], 0, (255), -1)    

imgplot = plt.imshow(mask1,cmap='gray')
plt.show()
```

Comment: Try thresholding using cv2.inRange() on the color of the cloth.

Comment: How to apply it can you share any python code to segment it out?

Answer (score 1):

You can do that in Python/OpenCV by using cv2.inRange()to threshold in HSV color space and then some morphology to clean the result of small holes and white spots.

Infile:

[image]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# load image with alpha channel
img = cv2.imread('shirt.jpg')

# convert to HSV
hsv = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

# create mask for shirt in hsv
# specify lower and upper ranges for h,s,v colors of shirt
lower = (0,30,120)
upper = (30,70,160)
mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, lower, upper)
mask = cv2.merge([mask,mask,mask])

# apply morphology to clean mask
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE, (5,5))
mask = cv2.morphologyEx(mask, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel)
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE, (17,17))
mask = cv2.morphologyEx(mask, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernel)

# save mask
cv2.imwrite("shirt_masked.png", mask)

# display mask
cv2.imshow('mask',mask)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Masked Image:

[image]